# Google Sheets + Apps Scripts, Copy/Paste from one sheet to another, but Paste into first empty cell in specific column (B)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

- I am trying to write a script that will copy data from a range on one sheet and paste to another in the first empty cell in column B. I have a script that can paste it into the first empty cell in the sheet and that works fine, but I have a static row of ID numbers in column A, so when it pastes the data it is way down the sheet. So, I need a way to skip over column A and paste into the first empty cell in column B. Hope that makes sense.
- The other part is there will be empty cells in column B sometimes. So it needs to skip over those to get the very last empty cell.
- I found a tutorial to get that last empty cell and have that working fine, but can't figure out how to incorporate it into a function that will paste the data. Here is what I have so far:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1dp5s8G9vFF5LzF5mAaY-JoySLGekh5UKHwt6jFcGOnA');
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Form'); 
  var range = ss.getRange('A8:H');
  var data = range.getValues();
 
     var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Vq_xX9cbC6OBAh1IRKsVKSPQvc5FEUFsJ2mlPzuFZ6o');
     var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Data');
     var columnToCheck = ts.getRange("B:B").getValues();
     var lastRow = getLastRowSpecial(columnToCheck);
  
  
     Logger.log(lastRow)
};
 

function getLastRowSpecial(range){
  var rowNum = 0;
  var blank = false;
  for(var row = 0; row < range.length; row++){
 
    if(range[row][0] === "" && !blank){
      rowNum = row;
      blank = true;
    }else if(range[row][0] !== ""){
      blank = false;
    };
  };
  return rowNum;
};
```

- So basically I need a function that will setValues(data) at the cell determined by "lastRow"
- Alternatively, if anyone has a suggestion on how this may be accomplished a different way, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

- You are very close. The `getLastRowSpecial` function indeed gets the last row of column `B` and it takes into account the blank cells.
- Your goal is then to use the returned value `lastRow` and set the data starting from `lastRow+1` by using [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).

  ```
  ts.getRange(lastRow+1,2,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
  ```
- Another modification I made in your script was instead of taking the full `data` range, I get only until the last row with content. If this does not work for you then skip that part and use your solution. This is the part I modified:

  ```
  var range = ss.getRange('A8:H'+ss.getLastRow());
  ```

---

### Solution:

I only modified `myFunction`:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1dp5s8G9vFF5LzF5mAaY-JoySLGekh5UKHwt6jFcGOnA');
  
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Form'); 
  var range = ss.getRange('A8:H'+ss.getLastRow()); // new code
  var data = range.getValues();
 
     var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Vq_xX9cbC6OBAh1IRKsVKSPQvc5FEUFsJ2mlPzuFZ6o');
     var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Data');
     var columnToCheck = ts.getRange("B:B").getValues();
     var lastRow = getLastRowSpecial(columnToCheck);
     
     ts.getRange(lastRow+1,2,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data); // new code

};
 
function getLastRowSpecial(range){
  var rowNum = 0;
  var blank = false;
  for(var row = 0; row < range.length; row++){
 
    if(range[row][0] === "" && !blank){
      rowNum = row;
      blank = true;
    }else if(range[row][0] !== ""){
      blank = false;
    };
  };
  return rowNum;
};
```